# view.getLocationOnScreen(locations) returns wrong Y coordinate

Tags: android

```
int[] locations = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
int x = locations[0];
int y = locations[1];
otherView.setLocation(x, y);
```

This results in otherView being verticaly ~somewhere in the middle of first view and not exactly a top of it.

This is basically the logic of setLocation method:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
layoutParams.x = mX;
layoutParams.y = mY;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

return dialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I notice you didn't ensure the margins of the default-generated dialog are zero.  Perhaps try this:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp...

    lp.horizontalMargin = 0;
    lp.verticalMargin = 0;
```